# Why dom node's scrollHeight is greater than its content height when it's child node is an svg?

Tags: svg

Below is a HTML dom node #root, which contains a svg as its only child node.

```
<div id="root" style="background-color: blue; height:100px; overflow:scroll; ">
  <svg>
    <rect width="50" height="50"
style="fill:red;stroke-width:1;
stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I expected that the node #root has scrollHeight 150px, since its child node svg svg.getBoundingClientRect().height 150px. But actually its scrollHeight is 154px. Can any one explain why svg child node is so special?

Comment: Please add `display:block;` to the svg element

Comment: Thanks! Adding "display: block" to svg can make the scrollHeight of #root. But it still doesn't explain my question. I have changed the demo xml.